# как использовать абсолютные координаты в java

Tags: java, swing, координаты

есть класс TheCraftingEra:

```
public class TheCraftingEra {
public static String GAME_NAME = "The crafting era";
public static int HEIGHT = 600;
public static int WIDTH = 800;
public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame fra = new JFrame();
Insets in = fra.getInsets();
fra.setTitle(TheCraftingEra.GAME_NAME);
fra.setSize(WIDTH + in.left + in.right, HEIGHT + in.top + in.bottom);
fra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
fra.setResizable(false);
fra.setVisible(true);
fra.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
fra.setLayout(null);

Container c = fra.getContentPane();
JPanel menu = new JPanel();
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
guiButton play = new guiButton(21, 200, "Play", menu);
c.add(menu);
}
```

В нём содержится метод main и JFrame.
Есть класс guiButton:

```
public class guiButton extends Component {

public guiButton(int x, int y, String text, JPanel pan) {
Insets in = pan.getInsets();
URL imgURL = TheCraftingEra.class.getResource("button.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
JLabel img = new JLabel(icon);
img.setBounds(in.left + x, in.top + y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
JLabel btext = new JLabel(text);
img.setIcon(icon);
pan.add(img);
pan.add(btext);
}
}
```

Почему когда я указываю любые координаты(например 21 и 20) у меня не добавляется картинка? ( я проверял на BorderLayout'е - там всё показывается, и ещё, чтобы картинку через JLabel вставить, надо использовать new JLabel(icon) или img.setIcon(icon)? )

Answer (score 0):

Что бы пользоваться абсолютными координатами, необходимо установить `menu.Layout(null)`. В этом случае каждому элементу необходимо задавать его положение и размер.
Если вы хотите что бы ваша `JPanel` занимала весь `JFrame`, необходимо убрать `JFrame.setLayout(null)`. Или же задавать JPanel` его координаты и размер.